# What is the purpose of the double underscore, after a single underscore, as a parameter to a function / class method?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In my exploration of Polymer Dart 1.0.0, I've found for events, and observer methods, I am forced to use this pattern

```
@reflectable
void someEvent([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

or on an observer method

```
@Observe('someField')
void someFieldChanged([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

I understand what the square brackets are for, optional parameters, I also understand that if you don't care about the passed parameters, you can represent this parameter with the underscore.  What surprised me was the examples I looked at used double underscore, __, as the second symbol between the square brackets.  When I tried to use just a single underscore again, I get a duplicate formal parameter error.  Is there some reason why the second parameter you don't care about has to be different from the first?  By this logic, if I include a third one, does it mean it'll have to be a triple underscore ___?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing special. `_` as `__` as `a` are just variable identifiers. `_` is often used to name an unused variable.
Here there are 2 variables unused, the first one is named `_` and the second one `__`.
With multiple unused variables it's common to name them `_`, `__`, `___` ...  or `_1`,`_2`,`_3`...

Comment: So this underscore to represent parameters you don't care about, is just convention, and as you said, the underscore can be used as a variable identifier?

Comment: Yes. An identifier in dart must start with `$`, `_` or a letter, and continue with zero or more of digits, letters, `$` or `_`. That means that `_` is just a variable, just like `a`. It has a private name, but since it's a local variable, that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Thanks.  You do tend to overlook these obvious things sometimes.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, the reason you have to use something like `foo(_, __, ___ )` rather than `foo(_, _, _)` is because you're naming your parameters `_` or `__`.  You're naming them with underscores because you don't care about them and you intend for them never to be used, but the system doesn't know that.  It'd be just like writing a function `foo(parameterOne, parameterOne)`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer 3.0 a single underscore stands for a protected property or method and a double underscore stands for members that are private to the class.

Please take a look into this reference for more information: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/properties